# How to use media shares in loki

Tags: pantheon-files, networking, bluetooth, switchboard

After enabling media shares in switchboard, I would expect to see my machine in the networks section in pantheon-files on another eOS loki machine in my network. I cannot find it anywhere. How do I find these? 
Also, when trying to send a file via Bluetooth (again enabled in switchboard, all settings always/askme/paired tried), it greets me with an error message (which just says there was en error without describing it).

Some additional information: i can ping between the machines, i can use bluetooth on both machines with other devices (just receiving files does not work, also not from android), there is no firewall in my network, I can access other windows shares without problems.

Answer (score 1):

The media sharing in System Settings uses a protocol called DLNA. This isn't a network file share like Samba. It's meant for smart media devices like Bluray players, TVs, etc.

If you want to share files to another computer, you'll need to set up a regular network share.